# Creating two vertical line cursors using aChartEngine Line Graph

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, linechart

So basically I want to create two cursors on our line graph depicted by vertical lines. Cursor A and Cursor B. We need the cursors to trace along the points of the graph on the X-axis (coloring the vertical line where the cursors are different from the graph. ex. graph is gray/black and the cursors are red and blue.)

I've been searching for a few days now and I can't seem to find anything about cursors or following along the plotted points of a graph in aChartEngine.

I've come to a point where I am debating using aChartEngine or switching to another library that has more capabilities.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I love aChartEngine and our graph looks great, I'm just lost in the creation of cursors on our Line Chart.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with AChartEngine as it comes out of the box.
However, you may be able to add a new series and add the points to it such as they create the visual effect of some cursors.